# how to delete space between buttons in grid? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

yo,
how to delete or decrease space beetwen objects in tkinter? i have a label and two radiobuttons in grid, when am starting an app it looks like the 'no' button text dissapears and i dont know how to fix this. columnspan doesnt help.

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    self.root.geometry('500x200')
    self.root.title('APP')
    self.root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    self.r = IntVar()

    self.root.link = Label(root, text='Link:', padx=15, pady=15, font=('Arial', 12)).grid(row=0)

    self.root.input = Entry(root, width=45, font=('Arial', 12)).grid(row=0, column=1)

    self.root.isplaylist = Label(root, text='Playlist?', font=('Arial', 12)).grid(row=1, column=0)
    self.root.playlistYes = Radiobutton(root, text='Yes', variable=self.r, value=1, font=('Arial', 12), padx=1).grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.root.playlistNo = Radiobutton(root, text='No', variable=self.r, value=2, font=('Arial', 12), padx=1).grid(row=1, column=2)
```

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] instead of just three lines of code.

Comment: @acw1668 yeah, already edited. My bad, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The `Edit` widget, `self.root.input`, is a bit wide, so `self.root.playlistNo` is pushed nearly out of the window.

Add `columnspan=2` on `self.root.input` to make it occupy two columns:

```py
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry('500x200')
        self.root.title('APP')
        self.root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

        self.root.link = Label(root, text='Link:', padx=15, pady=15, font=('Arial', 12))
        self.root.link.grid(row=0)
        self.root.input = Entry(root, width=45, font=('Arial', 12))
        self.root.input.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2) # added columnspan=2

        self.r = StringVar()
        self.root.isplaylist = Label(root, text='Playlist?', font=('Arial', 12))
        self.root.isplaylist.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.root.playlistYes = Radiobutton(root, text='Yes', variable=self.r, value=1, font=('Arial', 12), padx=1)
        self.root.playlistYes.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.root.playlistNo = Radiobutton(root, text='No', variable=self.r, value=2, font=('Arial', 12), padx=1)
        self.root.playlistNo.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

Result:

[image]

Note that `self.root.input = Entry(...).grid(...)` will assign the result of `.grid(...)` to `self.root.input` which is `None`.  So it is better to split it into two lines instead.

Comment: now its all clear. Thank you